# Project not works when I'm adding test support library

Tags: android, android-studio

I want use JUnit 4 framework in my android app and for that reason I added test support library and now my project now working. Here is the stack trace:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK LICENSE.txt
File 1: C:\Users\Damian\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit-dep\4.10\64417b3bafdecd366afa514bd5beeae6c1f85ece\junit-dep-4.10.jar
File 2: C:\Users\Damian\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit-dep\4.10\64417b3bafdecd366afa514bd5beeae6c1f85ece\junit-dep-4.10.jar
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "project.myapp.damian.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

compile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.0.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[Look here](http://sohu.io/questions/4773042/android-gradle-unit-testing-migration-from-jars-duplicate-hamcrest-files-from-j) and read the error message regarding the ignoring of license files. 
Pasted from android studio.

> You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
>     android {
>       packagingOptions {
>         exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
>       }
>     }